# How is relation between question and answer in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to do a basic question-answer web app without authentication by using ASP.Net5 MVC and Cosmos DB. I am able to do CRUD on question model. I guess I should do with 2 containers and Join operation but I can't include the other container. Here is my appsetting.json

```json
"CosmosDb": {
  "Account": "",
  "Key": "",
  "DatabaseName": "ToDoList",
  "ContainerName": "Items"    
}
```

Comment: But both the questions and answers in the same class (as properties) keep an array of them in the same container. If you are going to use a NoSQL database, you should read up a little on how the work

Comment: @Flydog57 - "NoSQL" is an umbrella term, and really doesn't define how any particular database works. You're also making a statement about using arrays, when you haven't seen any details about the OP's app usage (and then there's the issue of *unbounded arrays* and maximum document size to consider before moving content to arrays within a single document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no possibility** to do joins between containers in CosmosDB

[Read here](https://cosmosdb.github.io/labs/dotnet/labs/03-querying_in_azure_cosmosdb.html)

> Azure Cosmos DB’s JOIN supports intra-document and self-joins. Azure Cosmos DB does not support JOINs across documents or containers.

If you want to join data you have to eighter store both types of data in one container with a [good partitioning strategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview).

Second option is to read data from one and read from the other collection and then do joins in memory.

Comment: thanks, i think i will do partition in a single container.

Comment: FYI Joins cannot be performed between different documents, even in the same container, regardless of partitioning strategy.

Comment: @DavidMakogon ... of course thanks for this additional information. I would say its a *join like* query if you have the right partitioning strategy :)